# Wrong permissions (Group/user) for the occasional cache file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I've set all the permissions up and everything has been working perfectly for about 2 years until today when I force cleared the cache using `php artisan cache:clear`

Now, when the cache gets created in /storage/framework/cache, it works fine and all the permissions are set correctly *except* for the occasional file.

I could have thousands of cache files in there, all with the correct permissions (www-data as user and group). . but then randomly one file will generate using the wrong permissions which ends up with this error.

```
 file_put_contents(/.../.../storage/framework/cache/data/52/cf/52cf02760233b9fc625602f52fd0748a51ac772a): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

When I navigate to the file, the permissions are set to 744 and the user/group is set to root:root. Every other cache file is set to 774 and www-data:www-data.

I can fix it temporarily by running `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage` which sets the folders to the correct group and user but then the error appears again after about 15 minute once another file generates with the incorrect permissions.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Are you running any jobs or scheduled tasks in the background? If so try to get them to all run as the www-data user

Comment: I have jobs running in the background with supervisor.

Comment: Yeah, I've run into this issue when a daily `.log` file (inside of `storage`) was generated first by CLI vs Website. I don't recall the solution (ACLs maybe?), but that was the cause. If you're using `CACHE_DRIVER=file`, that could happen in this scenario too.

Comment: Clearing the .log files and setting the supervisor worker to `www-data` has sorted it. Thanks!